# Can I specify the order in which the joins occur?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

Say I have three tables, A, B and C. Conceptually A (optionally) has one B, and B (always) has one C.

```
Table A:
a_id
... other stuff

Table B:
a_fk_id (foreign key to A.a_id, unique, primary, not null)
c_fk_id (foreign key to C.c_id, not null)
... other stuff

Table C:
c_id
... other stuff
```

I want to select All records from A as well as their associated records from B and C if present. However, the B and C data must only occur in the result if both B and C are present.

I feel like I want to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B on A.a_id=B.a_fk_id
    INNER JOIN C on B.c_fk_id=C.c_id
```

But Joins seem to be left associative (the first join happens before the second join), so this will not give records from A that don't have an entry in C.

AFAICT I must use sub queries, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM B INNER JOIN C ON B.c_fk_id=C.c_id
    ) as tmp ON A.id = tmp.a_fk_id
```

but once I have a couple of such relationships in a query (in reality I may have two or three nested), I'm worried both about code complexity and about the query optimizer.

Is there a way for me to specify the join order, other than this subquery method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT JOIN b
                 INNER JOIN c
                   ON b.c_fk_id = c.c_id
         ON a.id = b.a_fk_id
```

The position of the `ON` clause means that the `LEFT JOIN` on `b` logically happens last. As far as I know this is standard ([claimed to be ANSI prescribed here](http://www.sharepointpromag.com/article/tsql3/letters-february-2004)) but I'm sure the downvotes will notify me if it doesn't work in MySQL!

Comment: Surprisingly enough, that works. I tested it against tables I created for my answer and it gives the same result as my version. This is syntax I've never encountered before so my first impression is that it will be hard for anyone else to understand it, given I'm decent at MySQL, but once you know what's going on, maybe not so bad. *shrug* Not sure, but I'll vet it works on MySQL 5.1.19.

Comment: MySQL does support nested joins since 5.0.1 ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html)).

Comment: @bfavaretto - Thanks for the link. Looks like this answer may in fact be missing some parentheses then?

Comment: @MartinSmith, I'm not sure, but I think the parentheses are optional (or at least not necessary in *some* cases).

Comment: Its really damn gud but didnt understand your query

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** And that's what I get for talking faster than I think. My previous solution doesn't work because 'c' hasn't been joined yet. Let's try this again.

We can use a WHERE clause to limit the results to only those that match the criteria you're looking for, where C has a valid (IS NOT NULL) or B does not have a value (IS NULL). Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON (b.a = a.a)
    LEFT JOIN c ON (c.b = b.b)
WHERE (c.c IS NOT NULL OR b.b IS NULL);
```

Without WHERE Results:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (b.a = a.a) LEFT JOIN c ON (c.b = b.b);
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | a    | b    | c    | b    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |    2 | NULL | NULL |
|    2 |    2 |    3 |    2 |    3 |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|    4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

With WHERE Results:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (b.a = a.a) LEFT JOIN c ON (c.b = b.b) WHERE (c.c IS NOT NULL OR b.b IS NULL);
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | a    | b    | c    | b    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |    3 |    2 |    3 |
|    3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|    4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Went with Martin's as it avoids a WHERE. IIUC the WHERE gets used after the join, so the other solution can eliminate rows earlier and is therefore more efficient. May be talking out of my bottom here tho. And the optimizer may take care of that.

Comment: If you'd like to know which query is more efficient, simply prepend them with an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). It will show you what indexes it will use, and approximately how many rows from each table it will have to consider to get its answer. It's good to hypothesis, but always try to confirm. I've had MySQL bite me with that odd optimization a few times on large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` for this.
When using this keyword the join will occur in the exact order that you specify.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: That won't allow entries from 'A' to show if 'C' has no entries. STRAIGHT_JOIN is _only_ a query optimization tool; it doesn't change the results that come back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought up another solution as well, and I'm posting it for completeness (Though I'm actually using Martin's answer).

Use a RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    b
    INNER JOIN c ON b.c_fk_id = c.c_id
    RIGHT JOIN a ON a.id = b.a_fk_id
```

I'm pretty sure every piece I've read about JOINS said that RIGHT JOINs were pointless, but there you are.